# why date format keep changing?

Tags: python, pandas

I am been struggling to understand this date format in pandas. Basically I'd like to remove hour:min:second so I can only keep year-month-day format.

here is the output:

```
df.index
atetimeIndex(['2021-07-01', '2021-07-02', '2021-07-03', '2021-07-04',
               '2021-07-05', '2021-07-06', '2021-07-07', '2021-07-08',
               '2021-07-09', '2021-07-10',
               ...
               '2021-12-23', '2021-12-24', '2021-12-25', '2021-12-26',
               '2021-12-27', '2021-12-28', '2021-12-29', '2021-12-30',
               '2021-12-31', '2022-01-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=185, freq=None)
```

from the above, you can see date format is year-month-day.

now when I use for loop to loop over index, the individual date becomes year-month-day hour:minut:second

```
for index_date,date in enumerate(df.index):
    print(date)
2021-07-01 00:00:00
2021-07-02 00:00:00
2021-07-03 00:00:00
2021-07-04 00:00:00
2021-07-05 00:00:00
2021-07-06 00:00:00
```

why the date format is not year-month-day? Thanks for your help

Here is the detailed screenshot

[image]

Comment: You're using a datetime type, this is just the internal representation. If you want something customized you can convert to string

Comment: You might want to do `for date in df.index.date:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `df.index`, you use the string representation of the `pd.DatetimeIndex` class whereas you use `print(date)` you use the string representation of the `pd.Timedelta` class.

```
>>> type(df.index)
pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex

>>> type(df.index[0])  # same as date in your loop
pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

Possible workaround for your loop:

```
#                                   HERE ---v
for index_date, date in enumerate(df.index.date):
    print(date)

# Output
2021-07-01
2021-07-02
2021-07-03
2021-07-04
2021-07-05
2021-07-06
...
```

Comment: Thanks Corralien,, so what is your solution? Thanks

Comment: I have the solution as @wjanndrea.